# How can I digitize a hand made logo without Photoshop?

Tags: logo, drawing

I'm graduating from High School, and I am in charge of designing the representative logo of my classroom. I made this logo, and I want to digitize it, I want to play with the colors and make it more Perfectly-sized.

My computer software is really old, so downloading Photoshop is not an option. Do I have any alternatives?

Comment: You should post the logo. It's hard to give advice without seeing how complicated it is.

Comment: Does "I want to digitize it" mean you do not have it inside your computer yet? (The current answers and the comment above seem to assume you have.)

Comment: If you don't have a scanner, you can find a well lit room, lay the logo flat on a table next a window with strong sunlight and take a picture from directly above it. Keep the camera level with the lens directly over the center of the subject to avoid skewing the image.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how complicated the logo is, you might be able to to get the job done with a simple vector graphics software. Photoshop is not an absolute necessity. There are open source (and free) alternatives. Have a look at [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) and [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/).

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Raiyan! Gimp, Inkscape and I believe you can get a free trial of Coreldraw still so have a go with one of those - they're less CPU intensive than the Adobe suite.

If your PC is okay to run it, you should be able to get a free trial of Adobe Creative Cloud which will provide you Illustrator and Photoshop, more than enough for what you need by the sounds of things :)