# Importing icons into Android Studio

Tags: icon, android, import

I made some icons using Krita. How do I get those icons into Android Studio?

Comment: Look at [the specifications](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but the specs don't tell you how to get your image from paper to (2d art, for example). It just tells you what size to make your icon, and then a bunch of specs on the icon after it's already been "brought into the computer". That part I understand, it's the preceding step I'm missing. Paper sketch to computer.

Comment: Use any graphics editor, like Inkscape, Gimp, Photoshop, Illustrator, etc.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [How can I digitize a hand made logo without Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/75672/23061)

Comment: Unfortunately that is the part I know how to do already. My question is not so much how to digitize it, but how to turn it into something usable by Android studio for an app icon. I'm sorry, I know it's weird because I don't know the correct terms to explain what I need better.

Comment: Do you mean how to [import your icons to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28700593/2065702)?

Comment: That is much closer! I understand importing them, it's the actual creation of them that I'm struggling with. It's already drawn and imported into Krita. However it's still just a picture of paper with something drawn on it. It is not yet an icon. So my steps remaining are: creating the actual icon itself, and then import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to describe is redrawing the icon, using image editing software - Krita will certainly work for this, as would Inkscape, or Illustrator, etc.

You could open the existing picture, create new layers on top, then use the original image as a guide to trace/redraw the shapes on those new layers. When finished you could delete the original image layer, then export the finished artwork as a PNG.

I used Inkscape for this example, but I'm sure you'll get the general idea

[image]

Comment: Exactly this! Is there a way to do it without handtracing it by mouse? Or is that pretty much just what it is?

Comment: My example was created manually using a mouse, in a few minutes. There's auto tracing in Inkscape and Illustrator, but it's not going to give you anything like a manually recreated icon. Sorry about that.  Lucky for me, or I'd be out of a job if creating artwork was that easy!

Comment: Ok, then mouse tracing it is! Thank you!